# Call external function in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, webstorm, sapui5

I'm trying to learn qunit test; I'm an OpenUi5 developer and I use Webstorm IDE every day.
Webstorm allows me to config a Karma run configuration. I have created a simple karma configuration file and I have wrotten a test file `test1.js`:

```js
test("Test function sum()",
  function() {
    ok(sum(0, 0) == 0, "the sum of 0 with 0 is 0");
    ok(sum(2, 0) == 2, "the sum of 2 with 0 is 2");
    ok(sum(2, 1) == 3, "the sum of 2 with 1 is 3");
    ok(sum(2, -1) == 1, "the sum of 2 with -1 is 1");
    ok(sum(-2, 1) == -1, "the sum of -2 with 1 is -1");
  });


function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};
```

Good! sum function is inside the same file. But now I want start to test functions in my `js` folder of the project (the unit test are in `test-resources` folder); for example in `js/util.js` I have `getShortIdGrid` function:

```js
//util.js file
jQuery.sap.declare("ui5bp.control");

ui5bp.control = {
  ...
  getShortIdGrid: function(sFromId) {
      if (sFromId.lastIndexOf("_") < 0)
        return sFromId;
      else
        return sFromId.substring(0, sFromId.lastIndexOf("_"));
  },
  ...
}
```

and this is my the my test:

```js
test("test getShortIdGrid",
    function () {
        equal( ui5bp.control.getShortIdGrid("shortId_123"), "shortId" ,"ShortIdGrid of 'shortId_123' is 'shortId'" );
    });
```

How can I call `ui5bp.controlgetShortIdGrid` in my test?

Karma console show me *ReferenceError: ui5bp is not defined*.

After loading properly the util.js file, how can I mange the declaration `jQuery.sap.declare("ui5bp.control");` on the top? I would like test my simple function without reloat the full library!

Comment: How did you include the util.js file in the test? Does it export the `ui5bp` object?

Comment: This is precisely the problem: I don't know how include `unit.js `. Using Openui5 framework, to use controlgetShortIdGrid  function I usually define as required ` jQuery.sap.require("js.util");` the file in my Component file and on the top of util.js file I write `jQuery.sap.declare("ui5bp.control");`

Then I can invoke the function by `ui5bp.control.getShortIdGrid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that **unit.js** is included in karma configuration file, `files` property, to make it available to karma. For example, if you have your unit.js located in /src folder, whereas your specs are in /tests, it would look as follows:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['qunit'],
        files: [
            'tests/**/*.js',
            'src/*.js'
        ],
        exclude: [],
...
```

That's enough to get  ui5bp resolved

Comment: Thankyou lena, now karma see util.js file! But I have a problem now: on the top of util.js file I have `jQuery.sap.declare("ui5bp.control");`, required to show the file by the openui5 framework, and the console show me this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'declare' of undefined
at http://localhost:9876/base/WebContent/js/util.js?b78f8003cbcefeb1a02ed1e325797c167e83bf9d:1`

Comment: answer is still the same - to get karma resolve all types used by you, you need to make sure to include the corresponding files in its configuration file